# Can I combine two cells but have different formatting of the components in the combined cell?

Tags: excel, formatting, formula

I have Large, Red and Book in cells A1, B1 and C1 respectively.  I want to combine them into cell D1 to get Large Red Book but I want each word formatted differently, eg Large in Bold, Red in Italics and Book in quotes.  How can I do this, please?

I thought Concatenatex was the way to go but I couldn't make it work

Comment: You need VBA scripting. Formula can't do that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The situation is that I have a list of names (First Name and Last Name in separate columns. I want to combine them into a Full Name column but with the Last Name in Bold (or possibly in Italics). Hence my request for various formatting styles.  I presume that once I know how to format one part of the combined cell in one way it should be easy to format the other part(s) in other ways.)